# can't open sockets for parallel cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to use the `parallel` package, and found that `makeCluster` fails to complete. I've traced the hang to the following line in `newPSOCKnode` :

```
con <- socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, 
    blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b", timeout = timeout)
```

That command stalls (granted the default timeout is a large value).  My suspicion is this is due to some "overzealous IT rules" laid down on our work computers, but would welcome any suggestions as to how to trace (and fix) the source of the problem.  This is Windows7-64, "Enterprise", R 3.0.1 .

More info:  inside debugging session, I set `timeout < - 10`, but it still hangs -- as though `socketConnection` is getting trapped somewhere that it can't even check the timeout value.

Here's my dump at the same point as Richie Cotton's data:

```
Browse[3]> ls.str()
arg :  chr "parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()"
cmd :  chr "\"C:/Users/carl.witthoft/Documents/R/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/Rscript\" -e \"parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()\" MASTER=localhost PORT=11017 OUT="| __truncated__
env :  chr "MASTER=localhost PORT=11017 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=2592000 METHODS=TRUE XDR=TRUE"
machine :  chr "localhost"
manual :  logi FALSE
master :  chr "localhost"
methods :  logi TRUE
options : <environment: 0x000000000ccac6a0> 
outfile :  chr "/dev/null"
port :  int 11017
rank :  int 1
renice :  int NA
rscript :  chr "\"C:/Users/carl.witthoft/Documents/R/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/Rscript\""
timeout :  num 2592000
useXDR :  logi TRUE
```

So aside from a different port number, I think everything matches up.

Next trick:  I opened a shell and ran `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 11017" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=11017`  and got an "OK" response.
I ran `netstat -a -n`  and found the following line:

`TCP    0.0.0.0:11017          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`

But running `makePSOCKcluster`  still hangs at the same place.

NEXT:
I tried running `R` from the command line (via cygwin bash), and the error message I get is `Error in loadhistory(file) : no history mechanism available
Execution halted` , after which -C returns me to the R-prompt.

Comment: Specifying the appropriate path to `Rscript.exe` in `makeCluster(..., rscript = <pathToRscript.exe>)` prevented that function from hanging for me. That was a while ago, though.

Comment: @BenBarnes tried that -- no go.  I checked; the default path was being correctly generated anyway.

Comment: The master hangs there because it is waiting for the worker that it just started to connect back to it.  The real problem is almost certainly in the worker.  Try using the outfile option to see if the worker threw an error or if it's also hanging because of a firewall.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the call to `makeCluster` since that controls how the workers are started.

Comment: @SteveWeston I tried that; no error (or at least, no file ever gets created) generated

Comment: If the "outfile" never got created, that means that something went wrong in starting the worker very early on.  I suggest that you try manual mode: `cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3, manual=TRUE, outfile="log.txt")`.  That may be the only way to see the error.

Comment: @SteveWeston nope, that hangs as well.

Comment: So the worker that you manually started hangs without an error message?  I would try debugging that worker to see where it is hanging  also.

Comment: @SteveWeston I plead naivete here: I don't know what a "worker" means. All I can tell you is that `makePSOCKcluster` does not finish and no outfile is created.  I can hit the `STOP` button in the Rgui but there's nothing new in my environment.  Just to be clear- I'm trying to create a cluster on my home machine's (i7) cores.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're describing is the classic problem with PSOCK clusters: *`makeCluster` hangs*.  It can hang for dozens of reasons because it has to create all of the processes, called "worker" processes, that will perform the actual work of the "cluster", and that involves starting new R sessions using the Rscript command that will execute the `.slaveRSOCK` function, which will create a socket connection back to the master and then execute the `slaveLoop` function where it will eventually execute the tasks sent to it by the master.  If anything goes wrong starting any of the worker processes (and trust me: a lot can go wrong), the master will hang while executing `socketConnection`, waiting for the worker to connect to it even though that worker may have died or never even been created successfully.

For many failure scenarios, using the `outfile` argument is great because it often reveals the error that causes the worker process to die and thus the master to hang.  But if that reveals nothing, I go to manual mode.  In manual mode, the master prints the command to start each worker instead of executing the command itself.  It's more work, but it gives you complete control, and you can even debug into the workers if you need to.

Here's an example:

```
> library(parallel)
> cl <- makePSOCKcluster(1, manual=TRUE, outfile='log.txt')
Manually start worker on localhost with
   '/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript' -e 'parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()' MASTER=localhost
PORT=10187 OUT=log.txt TIMEOUT=2592000 METHODS=TRUE XDR=TRUE
```

At this point, your R session is hung because it's executing `socketConnection`, just as you described.  It's now your job to open a new terminal window (command prompt, or whatever), and paste in that Rscript command.  As soon as you've executed it, `makePSOCKcluster` should return since we only requested one worker.  Of course, if something goes wrong, it won't return, but if you're lucky, you'll get an error message in your terminal window and you'll have an important clue that will hopefully lead to a solution to your problem.  If you're not so lucky, the Rscript command will also hang, and you'll have to dive in even deeper.

To debug the worker, you don't execute the displayed Rscript command because you need an interactive session.  Instead, you start an R session with a command such as:

```
$ R --vanilla --args MASTER=localhost PORT=10187 OUT=log.txt TIMEOUT=2592000 METHODS=TRUE XDR=TRUE
```

In that R session, you can put a breakpoint on the `.slaveRSOCK` function and then execute it:

```
> debug(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK)
> parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()
```

Now you can start stepping through the code, possibly setting breakpoints on the `slaveLoop` and `makeSOCKmaster` functions.  In your case, I assume that it will hang trying to create the socket connection, in which case the title of your question will be appropriate.

For more information on this kind of problem, see [my answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976175/2109128)

**UPDATE**

Now that this particular problem has been resolved, I can add two tips for debugging `makePSOCKcluster` problems:

- Check to see if anything in your .Rprofile only works in interactive mode
- On Windows, use the Rterm command rather than Rgui so that you're more likely to see error messages and output from using `outfile=''`.

Comment: I get the following:  ` 'C:/Users/carl.witthoft/Documents/R/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/Rscript' -e 'parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()' MASTER=localhost PORT=11017 OUT=mylog.txt TIMEOUT=2592000 METHODS=TRUE XDR=TRUE
Error in .External2(C_loadhistory, file) :
  'loadhistory' can only be used in Rgui and Rterm
Calls: loadhistory
Execution halted`  .  I'm hoping this means I need to modify my .Rprofile to avoid that loadhistory call.  I'll chase that down.

Comment: OK, removing `loadhistory` from `.Rprofile` avoids that halt. However, neither the bash terminal nor the Rgui returns.  I appreciate your help; if I ever solve this I'll post the answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You found and removed one problem that had to be fixed in order to create PSOCK clusters, but I can't say I'm surprised that you ran into another.  This is an error prone business.  Hopefully this information will help somebody sometime.

Answer (score 3):

Test 1: Does the obvious command work?

```
library(parallel)    
cluster <- makePSOCKcluster("localhost")    
parSapply(cluster, 1:5, sqrt)
stopCluster(cluster)
```

Test 2: Is your port blocked?

According to `?makeCluster`, the default port is `10187`.  Check with your network admin to see if that port is open.

Test 3: Do the variables passed in to `socketConnection` look right?

If I do `debugonce(parallel:::newPSOCKnode)` and then stepping to through to just before the call to `socketConnection`, the workspace look this this:

```
ls.str()
arg :  chr "parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()"
## cmd :  chr "\"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.2/bin/x64/Rscript\" -e \"parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()\" MASTER=localhost PORT=10187 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=2"| __truncated__
## env :  chr "MASTER=localhost PORT=10187 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=2592000 METHODS=TRUE XDR=TRUE"
## machine :  chr "localhost"
## manual :  logi FALSE
## master :  chr "localhost"
## methods :  logi TRUE
## options : <environment: 0x0000000010bf2518> 
## outfile :  chr "/dev/null"
## port :  num 10187
## rank :  int 1
## renice :  int NA
## rscript :  chr "\"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.2/bin/x64/Rscript\""
## timeout :  num 2592000
## useXDR :  logi TRUE
```

Are you getting the same things passed in?

Comment: Oddly, trying to `debug(socketConnection)` makes R hang for me, as does running the code snippet in the question straight from the global environment.

Comment: See my `ls.str` dump above.   BTW, isn't there some command (either in cmd.exe or from a cygwin bash window I can use to see what my port statuses are?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Take a look here for finding blocked ports.  http://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-windows

Comment: I added my foray into `netstat` and `netsh` to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, don't I feel like a complete idiot.

I went back to "The Three R's of Software Debugging"  (Retry, Reboot, Reload), and after rebooting my system and successfully doing the manual worker startups, I tried creating a cluster with `manual=FALSE`  and had immediate success there as well.

EDIT: I should make it clear that changing my `.Rprofile` from `loadhistory()` to `if(interactive() ) loadhistory()` was critical to successful use of the `cluster` functions.

I'm very grateful to Richie and Steve for all their helpful comments and suggestions.  I've certainly learned a bunch of stuff "under the hood," so the experience was quite positive at least for me.

(So I've no idea what WindowsOS thingie or broken call had been getting in the way, but all's well that ends well)

Comment: Did you add `loadhistory` back to your `.Rprofile`?  Was that necessary to fix the problem or not?

Comment: I really don't think this is the answer.  I think the problem was loadhistory.

Comment: @SteveWeston  while it's true that `loadhistory` was **a** problem,  that wouldn't explain the fix after restarting the OS.  I had shut down `R` and restarted `R` with the modified `.Rprofile` and still couldn't run `cluster` functions.  So there were two problems, one of which was `loadhistory` and the other remains a mystery.

Comment: It's impossible to prove that rebooting fixed a problem, and even if it did, it's an answer that doesn't help anyone.  I think that this answer obscures an important failure mode that you've uncovered with your experiments.  You shouldn't feel like an idiot at all.  You've uncovered something that could help other R Windows users that have trouble executing makePSOCKcluster.