# R: parallel makePSOCKcluster hangs

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I'm trying to connect to another computer via makePSOCKcluster:

```
library(parallel)    
cl <- makePSOCKcluster('10.0.0.107')
```

Unfortunatelly it hangs. I have done passwordless login with the help of ssh-keygen and ssh command in the console works on both computers.

I have also tried:

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster('10.0.0.107', outfile = '')
```

and got the following error:

```
starting worker pid=2937 on blabla:11225 at 17:41:20.364
Error in socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... doTryCatch -> recvData -> makeSOCKmaster -> socketConnection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
  blabla:11225 cannot be opened
Execution halted
```

Then suggested by Steve Weston's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248598/cant-open-sockets-for-parallel-cluster/19259825#19259825) I have tried the manual mode. I went step by step with debugging `slaveRSOCK` function. I got stuck on:

```
Error in socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
  blabla:11225 cannot be opened
```

I have also tried to open any port using

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 11000 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 11000 -j ACCEPT
```

and it's variations on both computers.

On both laptops I have the same version of R (R.3.2.2) and `parallel` package. One computer has Ubuntu 14.04 and the other - Kubuntu 14.04.

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked your router's configuration?

Comment: No, could you tell me what I should do?

Comment: You should take a look at your the device owner's manual for more info.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a port on **machine 1** for listening 
   `sudo nc -l <portnumber>` and leave the terminal open
2. From another terminal check if `netstat -an |grep <portnumber> |grep LISTEN` is showing the port as **LISTENING**
3. from **machine 2** , run `nc machine1 <portnumber>` and see if u are able to connect and type something

If the above works fine , then your router setup is correct.

90% chance that the issue is due to router and firewall settings.