# Error in makePSOCKcluster(names = spec, ...) : Cluster setup failed. 3 of 3 workers failed to connect

Tags: r, foreach, raster, doparallel

I am trying to recruit more cores to increases my processing time for some lidar data I am analyzing but I keep getting "Error in makePSOCKcluster(names = spec, ...) :    Cluster setup failed. 3 of 3 workers failed to connect." after I run this:

```
 UseCores <-detectCores() -1
cl <- makeCluster(UseCores)
registerDoParallel(cl) 
foreach(i=1:lengthcanopy_list)) %dopar% {
  library(raster)
  ttops <- vwf(CHM = canopy_test, winFun = lin, minHeight = 2, maxWinDiameter = NULL)
}
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966055/makecluster-function-in-r-snow-hangs-indefinitely) could provide you something useful to try.

Comment: notice that `length` has a missing parenthesis. Also, do not load libraries inside a parallelized code and use `FORK` instead or the `::` call to the package function.

Answer (score 5):

It seems a problem relative to recent versions of R. Until further updates, looking at this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692) on GitHub it seems there are two workarounds as follows.

Directly use this to create the cluster:

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, setup_strategy = "sequential")
```

Or for a long term solution add the following to your `~/.Rprofile`

```
## WORKAROUND: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692
## Revert to 'sequential' setup of PSOCK cluster in RStudio Console on macOS and R 4.0.0
if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1" && !nzchar(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_TERM")) && 
    Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Darwin" && getRversion() >= "4.0.0") {
  parallel:::setDefaultClusterOptions(setup_strategy = "sequential")
}
```

Even if this workaround was necessary for Rstudio users, it could be of general use, as it is useful also on my GitLab registered runner tests.

Comment: It's worth noting that this disables parallel processing.  It's a workaround in the sense that the code doesn't hang, and doesn't require extensive code surgery to switch from parallel to sequential processing.  But it's not a workaround in the sense of "running in parallel despite the bug with RStudio."

Comment: This is not only OSX related. I had the same issue on Manjaro Linux and as you suggested, running the `parallel:::setDefaultClusterOptions(setup_strategy = "sequential")` in my session solved the issue.

Comment: @DanHicks it runs in parallel, it is just creating the sockets sequentially. I just used it few minutes ago and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're working in RStudio, the problem was most likely [this bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692): changes in `parallel` created a conflict between R 4.0 and RStudio 1.3.something.  Your code isn't a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can't check it on my end, but I just confirmed that `cl = makeCluster(1)` behaves as expected in RStudio 1.4.1103, R 4.0.2, Mac OS 10.15.7.  So try updating RStudio and checking your code again.